# "Scanning new and updated MEF components"

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2015

I can successfully reproduce the problem at will.  Below  is my steps:
Environment: windows 10 Professional 64bit

1. Run vs_community_ENU.exe to install
2. Choose the Microsoft web and Developer Tools
3. Let it done installing
4. Open it for the first time, I can see the ASP.NET Web Application
5. Close the Visual Studio
6. Open it up for the second time, it will show some upgrade: "Scanning new and updated MEF components..." and two or three more of
   the undated
7. New project no long shows asp.net web application along with other templates

How can I fix this problem? I uninstalled and reinstalled it for 5 times already and the same thing happen again.  I even installed VS2015.1.exe but nothing happened

Answer (score 21):

Delete the contents of the following folder:

**%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache**

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Not only this solved the issue mentioned in the thread, it also solved another problem that I had!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :)

Comment: After deletion and restart, the "scanning process" is still happened omce. But after second restart, it will not shown anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete the contents of %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\MEFCacheBackup
as well as 
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

The deletion of both these folders sorted my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. If I run "Blend for visual studio" shortcut then in the new project, there is no asp.net templates along with others. But if I choose the standard "Visual Studio 2015" then those templates are there... So glad to find the answer because I keep remove and reinstall each time I accidentally close visual studio 2015 community